# Using express middleware in koa

Tags: node.js, express, koa

I have existing code which implements an express middleware. How can I use this middleware in a Koa application?

When I try to call `app.use(expressMiddleware)` in order to use the middleware in my Koa app, Koa complains that a generator function is required:

```
AssertionError: app.use() requires a generator function
```

So I guess that some kind of adapter or trick is needed here... ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Also, you can try koa-connect: https://github.com/vkurchatkin/koa-connect

It looks quite straightforward:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var c2k = require('koa-connect');
var app = koa();

function middleware (req, res, next) {
  console.log('connect');
  next();
}

app.use(c2k(middleware));

app.use(function * () {
  this.body = 'koa';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Funny thing, koa-connect was created at the very same day when I originally asked this question :)

Answer (score 5):

koa is incompatible with express middleware. (see [this blog post](http://www.jongleberry.com/why-you-should-and-shouldnt-use-koa.html) for a detailed explaination, especially the part 'Better written middleware').

You could rewrite you middleware for koa. The koa wiki has a special [guide](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/guide.md) for writing middleware.

The `req` and `res` that you would receive in an express middleware are not directly available in koa middleware. But you have access to the koa [request](http://koajs.com/#request) and the  koa [response](http://koajs.com/#response) objects via `this.request` and `this.response`.

Comment: Thanks Marco, though, I was hoping to find a way to work around this limitation...

Answer (score 3):

I have create koa2-connect on npm for koa2. https://github.com/cyrilluce/koa2-connect

```
npm i koa2-connect -S
// usage same as koa-connect
```

Because koa-connect's author haven't publish next version( npm i koa-connect@next didn't work ), and it is not compatible with webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware.